# for loop matrix construction

Tags: r

I am trying to construct a matrix in a for loop. I am declaring an empty matrix called matrix1 in my code and I am trying to fill it row-wise with the simulated x, y and z variables:

```
simulation <- function(ss){
nsim <- 100
matrix1 <- matrix(0, ncol=3, nrow=nsim)
colnames(matrix1) <- c("x", "y", "z")

for(i in 1:nsim) {
set.seed(i)
x <- relevel(as.factor(sample(1:4,ss, replace=TRUE)), ref="4")
y <- relevel(as.factor(sample(1:3,ss, replace=TRUE)), ref="3")
z <- relevel(as.factor(sample(1:2,ss, replace=TRUE)), ref="2")

matrix1[i, ] <- cbind(x, y, z)
}
return(matrix1)
}
```

Now, when I run this, I am getting an error:

```
Error in matrix1[i, ] <- cbind(x, y, z) : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

.

I don't see why that is happening since matrix1 has 3 columns and I am filling it recursively with the 3 variables x, y and z.

Comment: `cbind` is used to add columns. I think you want to use `rbind` instead

Comment: What I meant (and sorry if this was unclear) was that I wanted x, y, z to be added to 1 row, then in the next iteration add x, y, z to the follwing row. Hence, cbind makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Too fill it row by row, do like this (this is not efficient):

```
x = data.frame(name = character(), y = numeric())
for(i in 1:10){
   x = rbind(x, data.frame(name = letters[i], y = runif(1)))
}

#   name          y
1     a 0.09931082
2     b 0.85088120
3     c 0.39535348
4     d 0.08633770
5     e 0.08329996
6     f 0.46080032
7     g 0.39309986
8     h 0.01993358
9     i 0.96079532
10    j 0.19371701
```

If you have a lot of rows, this is very inefficient. In this case, you could try to pre-allocate the rows:

```
n = 10
x = data.frame(name = rep(NA_character_, n), y = rep(NA_real_, n))

   name  y
1  <NA> NA
2  <NA> NA
3  <NA> NA
4  <NA> NA
5  <NA> NA
6  <NA> NA
7  <NA> NA
8  <NA> NA
9  <NA> NA
10 <NA> NA
```

Then loop over the rows and columns to set the values.

```
for (i in 1:n){
    for (j in 1:2){
        # x[i, j] = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I figured it out!                                    matrix1 <- cbind(x, y, z) is the only change that needs to be made, it then works fine, it was an idexing error on my part. And as I mentioned in the previous comment, what I meant was (and sorry if this was unclear) was that I wanted x, y, z to be added to 1 row, then in the next iteration add x, y, z to the follwing row. Hence, cbind makes sense (and clearly works).